# Tangents of a Curve lie on a Cone

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that if all tangent vectors to the curve $α(t) = (3t, 3t^2, 2t^3)$ are drawn from the origin, then their endpoints are on the surface of a circular cone with the axis the line $x − z = y = 0$.

I can find $α'(t) = (3, 6t, 6t^2)$, of course, but I am not sure about what the rest means.  What does it mean for these tangent vectors to be drawn from the origin?  What does it mean for them to be on that cone? (In fact, embarrassing though it is, I must say that I do not understand the description of the cone.)

Comment: Usually, one thinks of the tangent vector as something attached to the point of the curve where you take the derivative. "Drawn from the origin" simply means that you look at it as a vector in the ambient space, attached to the origin.

Comment: Okay, so the equation looks the same (I just interpret it differently)?

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}$yes.

Comment: How do I show them to be on that cone?

Comment: my comment does not include that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line (axis of cone) is $$x(t)=t(1,0,1)$$ The distance of an arbitary point $(x,y,z)$ to this line is, using the projection $$\frac{x+z}{2}(1,0,1)$$ must be the magnitude of $$(x,y,z)-\frac{x+z}{2}(1,0,1)={1\over 2}\left(x-z,2y,z-x\right)$$ Points with constant distance will satisfy $$(x-z)^2+4y^2+(z-x)^2=a(x+z)^2$$ for some constant $a$ - distance from the axis is proportional to distance along the axis for a cone.

You can check that $$2(3-6t^2)^2+4(6t)^2=2(9-36t^2+36t^4)+4\cdot 36t^2=18+72t^2+72t^4$$ and $$(x+z)^2=(3+6t^2)^2=9+36t^2+36t^4={1\over 2}\cdot (2(x-z)^2+4y^2)$$ so the points lie on a cone as desired.